# Fail2ban and CloudFlare?

Tags: security, web, webserver, cloudflare, fail2ban

Just wondering if it is possible to use Fail2ban on a server with CloudFlare in front of it?

```
Server <-> CloudFlare <-> Internet
```

The issue is that it seems the incoming web traffic has the IP of the CloudFlare servers, rather than the originating IP.

For example, I banhammer people probing for vulnerabilities of systems not in use.

```
*.log:173.245.55.134 - - [12/Oct/2016:23:06:32 -0400] "GET /CFIDE/administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 403 5423 "-" "-"
```

The above appears to be an attempt to exploit ColdFusion... Whatever that is. So I banhammer them, but now the incoming IP is listed as CloudFlare, so that is not going to work.

[IP Lookup: 173.245.55.134](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/173.245.55.134)

```
General IP Information

IP: 173.245.55.134  
Decimal:    2918528902  
Hostname:   cf-173-245-55-134.cloudflare.com
ASN:    13335
ISP:    CloudFlare
Organization:   CloudFlare
```

Therefore, is it possible to still use fail2ban with CloudFlare in front of it? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, you can still use fail2ban to block IPs on your server. Since Cloudflare is a reverse proxy, however, you do want to make sure you have a solution to restore original visitor IP back to your server logs using Cloudflare and fail2ban at the same time.

Cloudflare KB on "[Can I still use fail2ban while using Cloudflare?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204073570-Can-I-still-use-fail2ban-while-using-Cloudflare-)"

Yes, you can, though you may wish to restore the original IP Address of your end user using something like [Mod_Cloudflare](https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare); their knowledge base contains a guide on [Restoring Visitor IPs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200805497-Restoring-Visitor-IPs).

Cloudflare are soon offering the ability to do [rate limiting in the Cloud](https://www.cloudflare.com/traffic-control/), you can sign up for their beta on their site.